# How to correctly set up permissions in VMware ESXi?

Tags: permissions, vmware, esxi

In **VMware ESXi (the FREE version)** there is a built-in user functionality (manage > users) which gives the ability to create roles as well.

When I in the host (host > actions > permissions) give the permission "no access", it gives the user no permissions. Furthermore when I then in the individual machines, want the user to be able to interact with, give the permission "administrator", the user can use VMRC for instance to "control" the VM. 
The user can then only see the VMs assigned to them.
This raises the question: How can the user see hardware configuration, connected portgroups, resource consumption, "VM options" etc., basically information about the machine assigned to them. As described, it only shows a small portion of the information and not everything like more specific information.

I have been told, that this can easily be done in the paid version, but I am unsure how to do it without the features, which the license give.

Furthermore it shall be mentioned, that I do not wish, that the created user can see all virtual machines!